# Specifying a custom template for the django-lazysignup convert view

Tags: python, django

In my urls.py I tried to pass the `template_name` argument to the convert view:

```
url(r'^convert/', include('lazysignup.urls'), {'template_name': 'chat/templates/chat/sign_up.html'}, name='convert')
```

That does not seem to have changed anything. Do I need to make a new view to call the convert view?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

I had to restart the server to get the changes to apply. Also the file path should just be `chat/sign_up.html`.